# kvm with virtio scsi and rbd

Tags: kvm-virtualization, scsi, qemu

I'm currently using virtio-blk but I'd like to change to the new virtio-scsi, especially because it supports trim/ discard. The host is an ubuntu quantal system (kernel 3.5.0, qemu 1.2.0).

This is how I start my guest:

```
kvm -cpu kvm64 -smp sockets=1,cores=2 -cpu kvm64 -m 1024 -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsihw0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 -drive file=rbd:data/disk-1,if=none,id=drive-scsi1,cache=writeback,aio=native -device scsi-hd,drive=drive-scsi1,id=scsi1,bus=scsihw0.0,channel=0,scsi-id=0,lun=1,bootindex=100 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x12,id=net0,mac=62:79:D8:1E:E0:BF,bootindex=200 -netdev type=tap,id=net0,vhost=on -enable-kvm -nodefaults -boot menu=on -vga cirrus -cdrom rbd:data/ubuntu-12.10-server.iso
```

The vm starts fine an I can connect using the console and vnc.

`info block` on the console show both drives are there:

```
drive-scsi1: removable=0 io-status=ok file=rbd:data/disk-1 ro=0 drv=raw encrypted=0 bps=0 bps_rd=0 bps_wr=0 iops=0 iops_rd=0 iops_wr=0
ide1-cd0: removable=1 locked=1 tray-open=0 io-status=ok file=rbd:data/ubuntu-12.10-server.iso ro=1 drv=raw encrypted=0 bps=0 bps_rd=0 bps_wr=0 iops=0 iops_rd=0 iops_wr=0
```

How ever the disk is not accessible in any way from inside the vm:

1. The disk is not shown in the bios boot menu. There's only the cdrom and network card (pxe).
2. When I boot ubuntu quantal (kernel 3.5.0) from the cdrom, it does not detect the disk, although I somewhere read virtio-scsi devices should be support as of kernel 3.4.0.

What am I doing wrong and how to get it working? :)

Answer (score 1):

To verify that your version of qemu supports virtio-scsi devices run the following command on your linux host:

```
kvm -device ? 2>&1|grep virtio
```

see for the following output:

```
name "virtio-scsi-pci", bus PCI, alias "virtio-scsi"
```